# Jenkins downloading maven utplsql plugin during build of project

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

My maven plsql project in Jenkins fails as it tries to download maven-utplsql-plugin-1.31.jar. This has been installed already via below commands

```
    mvn install:install-file -Dfile=maven-utplsql-plugin-1.31.jar -DpomFile=maven-utplsql-plugin-1.31-pom.xml
```

I have also installed jdbc jar using following

```
    mvn install:install-file -Dfile=ojdbc14.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc14 -Dversion=10.2.0.4.0 -Dpackaging=jar  -DgeneratePom=true
```

Maven project configurations in Jenkins are as follows.
 Source code mgmt is set as None.
 Build triggers is set as "Build whenever a SNAPSHOT dependency is built"
 Goals and Option value is set as "test".

But during build process it fails, please refer to the console log as below.

```
    Executing Maven:  -B -f C:\Users\609508723\Documents\maven\plsqltest\pom.xml install

    [INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/theserverlabs/maven/utplsql/maven-utplsql-plugin/1.31/maven-utplsql-plugin-1.31.jar
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
         [ERROR] Plugin com.theserverlabs.maven.utplsql:maven-utplsql-plugin:1.31 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact com.theserverlabs.maven.utplsql:maven-utplsql-plugin:jar:1.31 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR] 
    [JENKINS] Archiving C:\Users\609508723\Documents\maven\plsqltest\pom.xml to com.mytest.group.myparentartifact/my-utplsql-tests/1.31/my-utplsql-tests-1.31.pom

    Finished: FAILURE
```

I have added maven-utplsql-plugin-1.31-pom.xml as below.

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
       <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

       <groupId>com.theserverlabs.maven.utplsql</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-utplsql-plugin</artifactId>
       <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>
       <version>1.31</version>
       <name>maven-utplsql-plugin Maven Mojo</name>

       <dependencies>
          <dependency>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
             <version>2.0</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
             <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
             <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
             <version>1.4</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
             <groupId>junit</groupId>
             <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
             <version>3.8.2</version>
             <scope>test</scope>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
             <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
             <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
             <version>2.4</version>
          </dependency>
       </dependencies>
    </project>
```

Comment: Could you post the content of `maven-utplsql-plugin-1.31-pom.xml`?

Comment: Added the maven-utplsql-plugin-1.31-pom.xml in the original post as well.